Bound on the minimum eigen value
Prove or disprove $\lambda_n\geq\frac{\sum_{i<j} a_{ij}}{2m}$, where $\lambda_n$ is magnitude of smallest eigenvalue of symmetric matrix $A=a_{ij}$ with $a_{ii}=0$ and $a_{ij}=0$ or $\sqrt{5}\leq a_{ij}\leq (n-1)\sqrt{2}$ and and $m$ is non zero entries of Off-diagonal.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
